# how to insert only even records data into database in mule?

Tags: database, foreach, mule, batch-processing

I need to insert only even records data into the database through batch processing.

an example I have 100 records of data in that data only insert even records.

Answer (score 1):

The use case you are trying to implement is badly aligned with the Batch features. It is one of the [characteristics of batch processing](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/batch-filters-and-batch-aggregator#tips) that you have limited access to records:

> Batch streaming and access to items: The biggest drawback to using
>   batch streaming is that you have limited access to the items in the
>   output. In other words, with a fixed-size commit, you get an
>   unmodifiable list, thus allowing you to access and iteratively process
>   its items; with streaming commit, you get a one-read, forward-only
>   iterator.

You could try setting a [commit size of 2](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/batch-filters-and-batch-aggregator#aggregating-records-using-a-fixed-size), then use only the second element of each aggregator. Note that performance will probably be bad because of the low commit size.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a `Batch` component. You could settle for a `For Each` component and then have an `Expression` component with `flowVars.counter % 2 == 0`.